# The intersection of sets $\{n/1,n/2,n/3,\dots\}$ over $n=0,1,\dots$ is empty

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I find and prove I'm right, the intersection of sets $A_n = \{\frac{n}{1},\frac{n}{2},\frac{n}{3},\dots\}$ from $n=0$ to $\infty$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

It seems to me that the intersection is empty since, for any natural number $k$, $A_{k+1}$ does not contain $k$ (how can I argue about that?)

My question is how can I give a solid proof that the intersection is just empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A_0$ contains only one element, zero. So one simple proof involves showing that, for some $n \geq 1$, $A_n$ does not contain zero.

The reasoning you are considering won't work, since $A_{1+1}$ contains 1.

Comment: I can show that zero is not contained in $A_n$ but that just means that the intersection does not contain zero, how do I move on from here?

Comment: Nevermind, got it thanks!

Comment: Great! Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $k \in A_{k+1}$. Then $k = \frac{k+1}{a} \wedge a \in \mathbb{N}^+$.

$$\begin{split}
k = \frac{k+1}{a} \Longleftrightarrow ak &= k+1 &\Longleftrightarrow
(a-1)k &=1 
\end{split}$$

Since above is satisfied, $k$ has to be equal to $1$.
$$\left((a-1), k \in \mathbb{N} \wedge (a-1)k = 1\right) \Longrightarrow
\left((a-1)=1 \wedge k=1\right) \Longleftrightarrow\\
a=2\in\mathbb{N}^+ \wedge k=1\in\mathbb{N} $$

So, $k \in A_{k+1}$ if and only if k = 1.